# regex pattern for a range and above 127

Tags: regex, c#-3.0

I need a regex such that it matches following plus anything ascii above 127 (i.e 7F hex and above). Below works fine for the given range.

```
string pattern = "[\x00-\x1F]";
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Did it work? If not, why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the or operator |  (pipe)

```
string pattern = "[\x00-\x1f]|[\x7f-\uffff]";
```

FF hex would be the max ASCII value.

Here's a cheat sheet for further reference:
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet

Comment: I think the spaces should be removed in the character class? Also, the parenthesis are not needed here... and there are Unicode characters above 0xff...

Comment: Yes, so looks like the range should be more right [\x7f-\xffff]?

Comment: Use "\uffff". "\xffff" is the same as "\xff" + "ff".

Answer (score 0):

Either:

1. Accept characters in both ranges (with an alternation, `[a-b]|[x-z]`), or;
2. Use multiple ranges in a character group (`[a-bx-z]`), or;
3. Negate the inverted range in the character group (`[^c-w]`)

   - The negation includes *a whole lot* of things before `c` and after `w`, so it's not [necessarily] the same as the former two, but this can be used as an advantage.

The appropriate values of `a`, `b`, `c`, `w`, `x`, and `z` are left as a [trivial] exercise for the reader.

Happy coding.