# hex range pattern match

Tags: c#, regex

I am using the following snippet to match hex numbers with range, but none of them is matching. Later I converted into decimal as well and now it is obvious that the regular expression is faulty. Some hints will be good.

```
        string[] tests = {"F200", "F201", "F2FF","F100","FFFF"};

        const string regexPattern = @"\b[\uF200-\uF2FF]\b";

        Regex rx = new Regex(regexPattern,RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);


        foreach (string test in tests)
        {
            if(rx.IsMatch(test))
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is within the range.",test);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is not within the range.",test);
        }

        foreach(string test in tests)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The corresponding decimal value of " + test + " is: " + int.Parse(test, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
        }
```

I found the hint from [regex pattern for a range and above 127](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336635/regex-pattern-for-a-range-and-above-127)
 but it is not solving the issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regex pattern for a range and above 127](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336635/regex-pattern-for-a-range-and-above-127)

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to parse the number into a `uint` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801509/uint32-tryparse-hex-number-not-working) and then check the range via a normal numeric range check.  This seems like using a saw to hammer in a nail.

Comment: This is a regex Unicode char `\uF200`, this `F200` is a string of letters and digits.

Comment: Said another way, `"\uF200"` is a 1 character string, `F200` is a 4 character string. Not even close to the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the hex range of `F200 - F2FF` in string form, you need this regex.

`[fF]2[0-9a-fA-F]{2}`

Comment: Since option `IgnoreCase` is given, `F2[0-9A-F]{2}` would be more concise for same result.

Comment: @Andreas - I don't see any scenario where case insensitive is faster. `Regex1:   [fF]2[0-9a-fA-F]{2}
Options:  < none >
Elapsed Time:    0.27 s,   265.01 ms,   265006 µs
Matches per sec:   566,024


Regex2:   F2[0-9A-F]{2}
Options:  < i >
Elapsed Time:    0.30 s,   295.55 ms,   295552 µs
Matches per sec:   507,524`

Comment: So? I never said it was *faster*. I said it was more *concise* ("giving a lot of information clearly and in a few words; brief but comprehensive").

Comment: Perhaps I can't teach you about regex, but it seems I can teach you about SO, because that first comment wasn't just for you, it was also for anyone else who reads your answer. --- And, although this surprises me, it also seems I can also teach you about [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct). "but out" is not friendly language.

Comment: @Andreas - Yeah, doesn't really cover it bud. I consider any comments on my answers to be directly to me, not someone else. If you think someone will read my answers to gain wisdom, then don't pile on my answers with you're own  peculiar usage forms, especially when you don't know what you're talking about with regard to my answers. The bottom line, and common knowledge is that case independency adds a %15-30 overhead to performance since every source character is converted to lower case before comparison. Add heavy backtracking and it shoots up to as much as %40.

Comment: You point is good, *except* that you never told OP to remove the `IgnoreCase` for the performance gain, which means that OP would likely just assign your regex to `regexPattern` and keep the rest unchanged, in which case *my* comment makes perfect sense. If you're that nitpicking about minute performance gains in a regex that's going to be run 5 times, you should at least cover the topic in full. Not sure why you think I don't know what I'm talking about, but you certainly don't know how to write a good answer, according to your own standards.

Answer (score 0):

As sln aforementioned, in his comment you are comparing a string to Unicode characters.

You could easily get around this by changing your string array to:
`string[] tests = {"\uF200", "\uF201", "\uF2FF", "\uF100", "\uFFFF"};`

And, your regex to somthing like: `const string regexPattern = @"[\uF200-\uF2FF]";`

Leaving you with the resulting code:

```
    string[] tests = {"\uF200", "\uF201", "\uF2FF", "\uF100", "\uFFFF"};

    const string regexPattern = @"[\uF200-\uF2FF]";

    Regex rx = new Regex(regexPattern,RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);


    foreach (string test in tests)
    {
        if(rx.IsMatch(test))
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is within the range.",test);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is not within the range.",test);
    }

    foreach(string test in tests)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The corresponding decimal value of " + test + " is: " + int.Parse(test, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
    }
```