# How can I repeat the unicode character as the digits and characters with \d* and \w*

Tags: php, regex, unicode, character, digits

I have this regular expression:

```
\d*\w*[\x{0021}-\x{003F}]*
```

I want to repeat a digit, a character and a specific code point between 0021 and 003f any number of times.

I have seen that with \d*\w* you can make "a1" so the order doesn`t matter but I can only repeat the code point character at the end, how can I make that the order of that repetition doesn't matters like the digits and characters to make strings like: a1!a?23!sd2

Comment: `[\d\w\x{0021}-\x{003F}]*`

Comment: @Sam please do not intentionally defy Stack Overflow's simple page design by posting answers as comments.

Comment: Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8336827/2943403

Comment: That is not the solution, no need for an alternation.

Comment: @Thef ignore the first item, the second item expresses multiple ranges in a single character class.

Comment: @mickmackusa Ah you mean th `2.` part, is shows multiple ranges indeed. I added an answer as the comment given at the top matches the digits in 3 fold and allows an empty string as well. Maybe it is interesting to further readers. If you think this is a duplicate, we can close it.

Comment: Nah. @Thef I can't find a dupe that makes me happy enough to close with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `\w` also matches `\d`, so you can omit that from the character class.

Note that this part `{0021}-\x{003F}` also matches digits 0-9 (See the [ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com/) Hx value 21-3F) so there is some overlap as well.

You could split it up in 2 unicode ranges, but that would just make the character class notation longer.

Changing it to `[A-Za-z_\x{0021}-\x{003F}]+` specifies all the used ranges, but if you add the unicode flag in php, using `\w` matches a lot more than `[A-Za-z]`

To match 1 or more occurrences, you could use:

```
[\w\x{0021}-\x{003F}]+
```

See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2w5Q0z/1) and this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KSUIDl/1).